# Debugging: Mouseover function does not get called

Tags: javascript, debugging, function

I used to have something like this:

```
$(function() {
$(".PortfolioFade img")
    .mouseover(function() { 
                    popup('PORTFOLIO');
                    var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("images/paperclip.png", "images/paperclip-black.png");
        $(this).attr("src", src);
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
                    ;
    });
    });
```

And when I tried to turn this into a function and call it, it didn't work at all. The image was not replaced.

The following is the function and following call that did not work, and I am at a loss as to why it didn't work.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
   $('body').hide().fadeIn(1000);

   //Changing Fonts
   function changeFont(element, fontFamily, fontSize)
{
    $(element).css("font-family", fontFamily);
    $(element).css("font-size", fontSize);
}
    function ImageRollover(image_element, popup_name, original, replacement)
{
    $(element)
        .mouseover(function(){
            popup(popup_name);
            var src = $(this).attr("src").replace(original,replacement);
            $(this).attr("src",src);

        })
        .mouseout(function(){
            ;
        });
}

$(function) {
   ImageRollover(".Portfolio img",'PORTFOLIO',"images/paperclip.png","images/paperclip-black.png");
});


 });
```

Comment: try to see in firebug and see what is happening..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry, what I should've seen in the first place was that your `ImageRollover()` function declares a parameter `image_element` but then within the function you use `element`. So within the function change:

```
$(element)
    .mouseover(function(){
```

To:

```
$(image_element)
    .mouseover(function(){
```

(And forget about what I said before.)

<s>What your original version had but the new version doesn't is a document ready handler. Try putting the call to your `ImageRollover` function in a document ready as follows:</s>

```
$(function() {
   ImageRollover(".Portfolio img",'PORTFOLIO',"images/paperclip.png","images/paperclip-black.png");
});
```

You can't attach event handlers to elements that have not yet been parsed - the document ready handler is not called until the whole document has been parsed so at that point you *can* attach event handlers. Alternatively you can put your script somewhere after the elements it operates on, e.g., at the end of the body.

I'd be inclined to move the `ImageRollover` function declaration into the document ready too, just to keep it out of the global namespace (assuming you only call it from within the document ready), though this isn't necessary to make it work.

Comment: I did like so, but it didn't work either? Look above at the code, I updated it. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally left a bracket out in my code, which was a syntax error - I've now fixed it. However, from your updated question it seems you already had everything in a document ready handler so obviously that wasn't the problem.